# How to exclude a field from indexing in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is my database (`foo` is a top level collection)

[image]

I want to exclude `baz` field from indexing, so I created a single-field exeption index like this:

[image]

[image]

I'm getting the data using:

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('foo');
var snapshot = await collection.get();
for (var doc in snapshot.docs) {
  print(doc.data());
}
```

It prints

> {bar: 0, baz: 1}

Why wasn't `baz` excluded? What's the correct way of exempting a field then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloud Firestore is an indexed database. By default, when you write a document to Cloud Firestore, that document is added to the index of each field in that document in the appropriate place so that it is ready for your queries that use `orderBy` or `where` clauses.

Defining an exemption to this default behaviour as you have shown in your question will simply not create the index for that field - it doesn't omit that field from any requests for a document's data.

To omit a field from returned data, you would use what is called a *Field Mask*. In the past, the Firebase/Firestore SDKs supported using these, but the feature was removed back in the alpha days because it caused data contention and caching conflicts. The only API that I know of that still supports masking the returned fields is the REST API itself which uses a [`DocumentMask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) on supported operations.

For example, to show what the exemption you added is doing, here is a collection called `"someCollection"` that contains a handful of documents with the fields `"bar"` and `"baz"`:

```json
"someCollection": {
  "aaa": { "bar": 0, "baz": 1 },
  "bbb": { "bar": 0, "baz": 2 },
  "ccc": { "bar": 1, "baz": 0 },
  "ddd": { "bar": 1, "baz": 0 },
  "eee": { "bar": 2, "baz": 1 }
}
```

By default, the following indexes will be created:
[image: Firebase indexes of above data]

By adding the exception in your question, you disable building the index for `baz` which will prevent using queries like `orderBy("baz")` and `where("baz", "==", 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

As you will read in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview#automatic_indexing):

> By default, Cloud Firestore **automatically maintains** single-field
> indexes **for each field in a document** and each subfield in a map. Cloud
> Firestore uses the following default settings for single-field
> indexes:
>
> - For each non-array and non-map field, Cloud Firestore defines two collection-scope single-field indexes, one in ascending mode and
>   one in descending mode.

By creating a single-field index exemption for one field, you actually exempt the field from this automatic indexing, but **it does not mean that that the field will not be returned by queries**.

More precisely, Firestore queries executed via the Client SDKs (including the [Flutter plugin](https://firebase.flutter.dev/)) return the entire documents corresponding to the query, i.e. all the fields of the document (independently from the fact that some of these fields are excluded from the automatic indexing).

---

Note that with the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) you can use a [`DocumentMask`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/DocumentMask) when fetching documents, which will "restrict a get operation on a document to a subset of its fields". This is not possible with the Client SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the doubt I actually had was what it means to exempt a field from the database.